# Installing Microsoft ttf fonts on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, truetype, opentype

I want to install a Microsoft Vista TTF font (lets say [Consolas](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000969.html)), on Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty Jackalope).

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/19824/better-ubuntu-fonts

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This](http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/09/installing-microsoft-fonts/) article explains how to install the Microsoft fonts on Ubuntu step by step. It's part of the Universe repository.

[This](http://embraceubuntu.com/2007/09/16/installing-vista-fonts-in-ubuntu/) article explain how to install the Vista fonts which includes Consolas on Ubuntu. You need to extract the fonts from the Microsoft Powerpoint Viewer.

Comment: Extracting those fonts from the MS Powerpoint Viewer is probably illegal though...

Answer (score 24):

If you've got a Windows machine handy (IANAL but I think you need a Vista licence in order to legally use the Consolas font), copy the file somewhere convenient.

Then in a terminal:

```
sudo cp *.ttf /usr/local/share/fonts
cd /usr/local/share/fonts
sudo chown root:root *.ttf
sudo fc-cache
```

Comment: IANAL wins the award for "most visually jarring acronym" every time.

Comment: +1 to therefromhere for straightforward response, and +1 to Telemachus for pointing out the visual connection vis-a-vis Freudian subtlety with the acronym used.

Comment: If you have a Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 license, you can also legally use Consolas: http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=22E69AE4-7E40-4807-8A86-B3D36FAB68D3&displaylang=en

Comment: Doesn't work. No changes in ST3

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks) script.

> **winetricks** is a quick and dirty script to download and install various redistributable runtime libraries...